# when we use an dem Platz und auf dem Platz (difference)

Tags: difference, preposition

Ich habe diese Sätze gefunden :

> Wo ist bitte das Cafe? - Das ist **an** dem Rosenplatz.
>
> Wo ist der Markt? - **Auf** dem Kirchplatz.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/when-would-one-use-im-and-am-rather-than-in-dem-and-an-dem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the difference is clear:

> "An dem (oder am) Rosenplatz"

means that the Café is located **adjacent** to the place.

> "Auf dem Platz"

means on **top of it**.

A "Markt" (market), not to be confused with "Supermarkt" (market center) in an European city, is comparable to a bazar, so it consists of "Stände" (counters with a tent) that are placed on the market place. See the image from a market in Germany (From de.wikipedia article "Markt"): [image: this image from Wikipedia] .

Colloquially, sometimes the wrong preposition is used, but that is bad style.

Comment: I'd like to add that "Markt" is also used in an abstract sense as "market" ... as in stock market... you will find "am Markt" in that context a lot.