# When do we use prepositions “in” or “auf” with locations?

Tags: preposition, wechselpraeposition

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Wir treffen uns ..  "in der"  oder "am" .. Musterstraße 3?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/wir-treffen-uns-in-der-oder-am-musterstra%c3%9fe-3)*

1. What is the difference between *auf dem Markt* and *in der Markt?*

I mean, when we use *in* and when *auf?*

2. What is the difference between the following two:

   > Justyna ist in dem Geschäft.
   >   Justyna ist in das Geschäft.

Comment: To better guide you with prepositions please [edit] your question for complete sentences (prepositions very much depend on their surroundings).

Comment: Related: [when we use an dem Platz und auf dem Platz (difference)](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/when-we-use-an-dem-platz-und-auf-dem-platz-difference)

Answer (score 2):

1) You just found something that is quite complicated for foreign speakers to learn in German language. If we are speaking about a specific address or a city German speakers are using "in".

Example-time:

> Wir treffen uns **in** Frankfurt.
>
> Wir treffen uns **in** der Frankfurter Straße.

The Straße in "Frankfurter Straße" does not mean the street itself as an object. You don't stay directly on the street. First example should be clear: You are meeting somewhere in the city of Frankfurt.

At the beginning "meeting **in** a **street**" may sound weird, but it's the way we say it. When you say "**auf** der Straße" you usually mean outside at the street or on the walkway.

Same thing with the "Markt":

> 1. Wir treffen uns **auf** dem Markt
>
> *This could mean a) on the marketplace outside, or b) if there is a specific market like "Wochenmarkt" which can also take place inside a hall, it could mean that you are meeting **in** the hall, but **at** the market.*
>
> 2. Wir treffen uns **in** de*m* Markt
>
> *This usually means that you are meeting at a **super**market. It's in a closed building and you are meeting into that building.*

---

2) The difference is pretty easy: The first one is correct, the second one isn't. You are using the wrong *Kasus*. It has to be "in dem Geschäft".

Comment: +1.In the last case the wrong way could be used sloppily when leaving out a trailing 'gegangen': wo ist denn Julia? - Die ist kurz in das Geschäft.

Answer (score 1):

About your second question, "Justyna ist in dem Geschäft." is correct. Because whenever you want to use the "in" preposition before a specific place, and your sentence does not include any movements associated with the place, it has to be written in Dativ form.