# What kind of word is `im` in the below sentence

Tags: preposition, german-to-english, article

What kind of word is *im* in the below sentence?

> Arbeiten Sie zu zweit. Sehen sie das Bildlexikon an und schreiben Sie fünf Sätze wie **im** Beispiel.

Comment: Any dictionary should be able to answer your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a sentence. It is a sentence fragment.

Comment: We have some related questions that might help you to understand: [When would one use im and am rather than in dem and an dem?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/when-would-one-use-im-and-am-rather-than-in-dem-and-an-dem?r=SearchResults&s=2|41.4550), [When to use bei/bei der/beim and in/im/in der?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/when-to-use-bei-bei-der-beim-and-in-im-in-der?r=SearchResults&s=1|43.7214)

Comment: @peterh, really? **This** should be the reason to consider it an off-topic question? ;-)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I voted to close as off-topic on the reason I stated. The question was closed by a different reason what I disagree: it is clearly not an information what would exist in any dictionary, it is an interesting grammatical question, because "im" is here the mix the preposition "in" and the article "dem". The probably reason of the close-voters was the unclarity. Because the question was edited to clear since then, I voted to reopen this question now.

Comment: @peterh, my first try already disproves your claim: https://www.dwds.de/wb/im.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ok, thanks. There is no way to retract a reopen vote, and I still consider this question interesting and grammatical. But I admit that there are answers in dictionaries. Maybe in the form "how to determinate the kind of the mix of two words of different kinds" would be even reopenable.

Answer (score 2):

The word *im* is a [preposition](https://www.dwds.de/wb/im).

---

<sup>Just a comment: It wouldn't have demanded a great deal to figure this out by yourself, especially, since the [English counterparts](https://www.dict.cc/?s=im) *at* and *in (the)* are also prepositions.</sup>

Comment: *Im* is a contraction of *in dem*, so strictly speaking, it is not a preposition but a combined preposition (*in*) and article (*dem*).

Comment: @RHa and I think that is exactly the problem here - This contraction is a phenomenon other languages (like English, and unlike Spanish, for example) don't have.

Comment: @tofro I think that the English contraction of *can not* to *can't* is quite the same phenomenon - it just doesn't occur in a *preposition*.